# Custom window in the bootstrapper as default window

Tags: wpf, prism

What should be the procedure to set a custom RibbonWindow as the default shell window.
We are getting this window from a module. Which we registered and initialized.

```
    protected override DependencyObject CreateShell()
    {
        return new xamRibbonWindow() as DependencyObject;
    }


    protected override void InitializeShell()
    {
        base.InitializeShell();
        App.Current.MainWindow = (xamRibbonWindow)Shell;
        App.Current.MainWindow.Show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

While, it is a little unusual to get the Shell from a module, you could do it exactly the same way it is normally done. Are you using a dependency injection container? I'm going to assume you are:

```
protected override System.Windows.DependencyObject CreateShell()
{
    return ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance<Shell>();
}
```

You could just substitute your XamRibbonWindow class for Shell. This way, you do not need to reference the project directly that includes your shell. If you want the ability to resolve more than one shell depending on the modules that are loaded, I would create an interface IShell which XamRibbonWindow implements and register that type with the container.

Edit:
Regarding your comments, I would have the module load and on intialize resolve the IRegionManager and call .Add on your region. Or have the shell call NavigateTo if you are using the Navigation interface

Are you using View Discovery or View Injection? (You may need to review the Prism book on UI composition) Also, using MEF, Unity?

Comment: The Shell is in the Shell not a module. The RibbonWindow is generated inside a module and I want to use it in the bootstrapper.

Comment: And Shell is the main project.